# Replacing 3 bulb chandelier with 5 bulb chandelier

Tags: lighting

Is it safe to replace a 3 bulb chandelier with a 5 bulb chandelier without overheating the house wiring?

The original fixture has 3 incandescent bulbs rated for 60 watts. I am looking at a fixture that takes 5 60 watts incandescent bulbs, however, I plan to use LED bulbs on it.

Comment: Welcome to DiY! Probably, but you'll have to add some more information. Which kinds of lights were in the old chandelier, has it ever been fitted with incandescent bulbs, and if so, which wattage did they have? Will the new one be fitted with LED lights or something else? If so, what power will these draw?

Comment: The original fixture has 3 incandescent bulbs rated for 60 watts. I am looking at a fixture that takes 5 60 watts incandescent bulbs. I plan to use LED bulbs on it. I haven't bought it yet.

Comment: You should be fine then, LED bulbs use about an eighth of incandescent ones. Go with crip659's answer :)

Answer (score 6):

Incandescent light bulbs use about 1 amp for 120 watts, or less.  LEDs use much less.

A normal/common light circuit has a 15 amp breaker protecting it, about 15 incandescent bulbs worth of power.  Maybe 50 to 100 LEDs

Would need to map out(check what the circuit powers) the circuit to be sure, but most times two extra bulbs will not heat up or overload a circuit(unless they are high power).